# swagger-codegen skipping invalid property type:array

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0

On running `java -jar swagger-codegen-cli.jar generate -i ../tech-bucket/membership-card/apis/mini.swagger  -l nodejs-server` against the swagger spec below, I see two errors/warnings:

```
[main] ERROR io.swagger.codegen.DefaultCodegen - unexpected missing property for name actual_things
[main] WARN io.swagger.codegen.DefaultCodegen - skipping invalid property {
  "type" : "array"
}
[main] ERROR io.swagger.codegen.DefaultCodegen - unexpected missing property for name actual_things
[main] WARN io.swagger.codegen.DefaultCodegen - skipping invalid property {
  "type" : "array"
}
```

I don't understand what's invalid about specifying `type: array`. How else do I express that the API returns an array of objects? That is, the API returns something that looks like:

```
{
    formatted_input: "Here is the formatted input",
    actual_things: [
        {id: "10", thing_value: "the value for number 10"},
        {id: "12", thing_value: "the value for number 12"}
    ]
}
```

The swagger spec in error is:

```
swagger: '2.0'

info:
  version: "1"
  title: title here
  description: description here

paths:
  /endpoint:
    get:
      description: an endpoint
      parameters:
        -
          name: someparam
          in: query
          description: param desc here
          required: true
          type: string
      responses:
        200:
          description: List of things
          schema:
            title: thing_list
            type: object
            properties:
              formatted_input:
                type: string
                description: The passed input
              actual_things:
                type: array
                items:
                  -
                    type: object
                    properties:
                      thing_value:
                        type: string
                        description: The thing
                      id:
                        type: string
                        description: an ID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `items` is a magic keyword which defines that all items in this collection use the following schema. We do not need to actually make it a YAML array item. So, working swagger spec looks like:

```
swagger: '2.0'

info:
  version: "1"
  title: title here
  description: description here

paths:
  /endpoint:
    get:
      description: an endpoint
      parameters:
        -
          name: someparam
          in: query
          description: param desc here
          required: true
          type: string
      responses:
        200:
          description: List of things
          schema:
            title: thing_list
            type: object
            properties:
              formatted_input:
                type: string
                description: The passed input
              actual_things:
                type: array
                items:
                  type: object
                  properties:
                    thing_value:
                      type: string
                      description: The thing
                    id:
                      type: string
                      description: an ID
```

Comment: diff for those who are having a hard time spotting the difference between the broken and working code: https://www.diffchecker.com/rHgYlLyk